# Recommended knowledge for Applied Math

Tags: applications

I would like to know which topics below are important for applied math and why?
If you know about only one subject, share your answer with me please.

- Topology
- Set Theory
- Linear Algebra
- Abstract Algebra
- Graph Theory
- Geometry
- Calculus
- ODE
- PDE
- Chaos Theory
- Dynamic Systems

Comment: This depends on what kind of applied math you are interested in. Some areas make heavy use of functional analysis, and thus you would need to know a fair amount of general topology, linear algebra, measure theory, and algebra. Other areas are primarily combinatorial and graph-theoretic, and thus little general topology would be needed, but you might need to know a bit of combinatorial topology. Still other areas are different still  . . .

Comment: Applied Mathematics is huge. What field specifically?

Comment: About ODE's and PDE's for example

Comment: I can go down that entire list and give you reasons that each is HUGHLY important for applied mathematics. PDEs and ODE arise naturally any time you use math to model something where changes in one measurment (for example time), results in changes in another variable (for example, distance travelled). Which is pretty hard to avoid in a mathematical model. Every science comes with a collection of important differential equations.